# Adding a progress bar to copy file script

Tags: powershell

```psh
$destinationFolder = "C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\Saves"
$rootFolder = "C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\test"
$subFolder = "\sales"
$fileName = "hello.txt"

$Dir = get-childitem $rootFolder |
       select -first 10 |
       ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } |
       Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_.Name, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }

[array]::Reverse($Dir)

$Dir | format-table FullName

Foreach ($i in $Dir){
  if(Test-Path $($i.FullName + $subFolder + "\" + $fileName)){
    #echo $($i.FullName + $subFolder)
    get-childitem $($i.FullName + $subFolder) |
      where {$_.Name.ToLower() -eq $fileName.ToLower()} |
      Copy-Item -Destination $destinationFolder
    echo $("just copied " + $fileName + " from " + $i.FullName.Trim())
    break;
  }else{
    echo $("Could not find " + $fileName + " in " + $i.FullName.Trim())
  }
}
```

I usually use this script to copy large files from one location to another. I want to add a progress bar so I have some indication of the file being copied etc.

I would like to add a `write-progress [ooooo     ]` type of thing, but I'm unsure how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

replace your foreach statement with this :

```
$i=1
$dir| %{
    [int]$percent = $i / $dir.count * 100
    Write-Progress -Activity "Copying ... ($percent %)" -status $_  -PercentComplete $percent -verbose
    copy $_.fullName -Destination $destinationFolder
    $i++
}
```