# Command in ForEach-Object script block unexpectedly prompts for arguments

Tags: powershell, syntax, pipeline

I have the following script

```
$sourceRoot = "C:\Users\skywalker\Desktop\deathStar\server"
$destinationRoot = "C:\Users\skywalker\Desktop\deathStar/server-sandbox"
$dir = get-childitem $sourceRoot  -Exclude .env, web.config   

Write-Output "Copying Folders"
$i=1
$dir| %{
    [int]$percent = $i / $dir.count * 100
    Write-Progress -Activity "Copying ... ($percent %)" -status $_  -PercentComplete $percent -verbose
    copy -Destination $destinationRoot  -Recurse -Force
    $i++
```

I tried to reference this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920173/adding-a-progress-bar-to-copy-file-script), but I ended up getting the following prompt in the powershell console.

> Supply values for the following parameters:
>
> Path[0]:

Comment: what is the rest of the error text? it _usually includes the line number AND at least part of the line of code ...

Comment: It’s not an error it’s actually asking me to input values for the path[0], because if I type something then it goes to path[1]... so I’m not sure what’s going on. And I should add I’m a newbie PS scripted

Comment: ah! i misunderstood. [*blush*] so ... do you know what cmdlet is producing that prompt? i suspect it is the `copy -Destination` line since you have that INSIDE a `ForEach-Object` block ... and didn't pass any source to it.

Comment: No worries, you were right for sure.

Comment: kool! glad that you got it working ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using **`%` ([`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object))** to process input from the pipeline (`$dir`) object by object.

**Inside the script block (`{ ... }`) that operates on the input, you must use the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#_) to reference the pipeline input object at hand** - commands you use *inside the script block* do *not* themselves automatically receive that object as their input.

Therefore, your `copy` (`Copy-Item`) command:

```
copy -Destination $destinationRoot  -Recurse -Force
```

lacks a source argument and must be changed to something like:

```
$_ | copy -Destination $destinationRoot  -Recurse -Force
```

Without a source argument (passed to `-Path` or `-LiteralPath`) - which is mandatory - `Copy-Item` *prompts* for it, which is what you experienced (the default parameter is `-Path`).

In the fixed command above, passing `$_` via the pipeline implicitly binds to `Copy-Item`'s `-LiteralPath` parameter.